# Laravel 5.1: Pagination on Models with hasManyThrough()

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.1, has-many-through

I have "Brand" `hasManyThrough` "MarketProduct" through "Product". So,

```
Brand >> Product >> MarketProduct
```

where `>>` represents a `hasMany` relationship. I'm able to get a collection (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`) of `MarketProducts`as below using the `hasManyThrough()` method defined in `Brand`.

```
$collection = Brand::find($someId)->marketProducts;
```

The issue is that `$colletion` is not an instance of the Query Builder or Eloquent, so I can't use `->paginate($num)`. Is it possible to use the default pagination feature when using `hasManyThrough`, or do I need build the query manually to use the pagination?

Comment: Have you tried `$collection = Brand::find($someId)->marketProducts(); `

Comment: Nice. `->marketProducts()` returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough`, which can use the pagination! I also see a part in the official documentation where it mentions this. Feel free to write up an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea if I can fetch "from" and "to" from this? Document shows the paginator JSON having it, but I don't think it's one of the helper methods.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. I have laravel a bit forgotten, if you could be more specific :)

Comment: So, if I'm on page 2 of the results with each page displaying 5 results, I'm showing records 6 to 10. "From" would be 6, and "To" would be 10 here.

Comment: And you want to get that 2 results, may be to show on the pagination, is that? I don't think there is a easy way to achive that, you could manually create the pagination.

Comment: @Gonzalo: No, I just want the number `6` and `10`, so I can print "displaying records 6 to 10".

Comment: Ahhh ok. Then you just have to make the calculation by your self. If I remember well laravel pagination gives you some info like current page and items per page. With that info you can get the showed items: `((current_page - 1) *  items_per_page) + 1 =  first_item`. Example with page 1: `From: ((1 - 1) * 5) + 1 = 1` `To: first_item - 1 + items_per_page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [document](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), it mentions

> ...since all relationships also serve as query builders, you can add
>   further constraints to which comments are retrieved by calling the
>   comments method and continuing to chain conditions onto the query...

So the solution is:

```
$collection = Brand::find($someId)->marketProducts();
```